# Asking for good books on Physical Fitness?

Tags: discussion, questions

I'm looking for good books about medical aspects in Physical Fitness and on how the body reacts on products like BCAA, creatine and so on. Can I ask this kind of questions on Physical Fitness without being attacked by downvoters? If I can't how should I pose the question?

Comment: These questions are not on topic on any site.  If what you want is a book recommendation, go to another site, say Amazon, to get your recommendations.

Comment: This is probably a question better asked on their own meta

Comment: @Servy not really. According to [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156789/are-book-recommendation-questions-acceptable-on-some-sites-but-not-others), it might be fine on some sites in the network.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Great minds and all that

Answer (score 1):

This kind of question is not something that is accepted here. It's been tried before in the early months, and any type of list-based questions were received badly.

However, there have been answers that do reference books, but this depends entirely on asking a *specific* question instead of a vague, broad, give-me-everything type of question. It depends on what you want to ask so take a look at our [scope](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and browse the site to get a better idea of what is on our site.